# Set image order and load priority

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm building an web app with PHP where users upload images and they're displayed publicly on a main index.php file. My problem is premium members get features, one of which allows you to upload a larger picture and keep them at the top so they can be above all others for a longer period of time.

Any idea how to do this so that a MySQL field can easily control this.

Thanks

Comment: Any thoughts as to how you might go about implementing this? Does it help if I give you `ORDER BY` as a hint?

Comment: I don't know what to try do nothing. I'm looking for suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `expiration_date` column and insert a further out date into this column for the pictures when a premium user uploads an image and then `ORDER BY expiration_date DESC` will keep the soonest to expire on the bottom.

Comment: Wow i never even thought of that. Thanks